# What happens next when we yield a request in parse_item in scrapy spider?

Tags: python, post, scrapy, yield

I was using scrapy HTTP POST method to crawl a website, however, some weird problems keep bothering me and I do not know where goes wrong.
Here is my sample code:

```
def parse(self, response):
    sel = Selector(response)
    # to generate next page
    next_formdata = sel.css("next")
    yield FormRequest(url=self.start_urls[0], 
                              formdata=next_formdata,
                              callback=self.parse)

    # to parse item
    items = sel.css("items")
    for item in items:
        cur_formdata = item.css("form")
        yield FormRequest(url=self.start_urls[0],
                              formdata=cur_formdata,
                              callback=self.parse_item)

def parse_item(self, response):
    sel = Selector(response)
    if len(sel.extract()) < 10000:
        new_request = response.request.copy()
        yield new_request

    log.msg("item length is" + str(len(sel.extract())))
    item = MyItem()
    # get specific information
    yield item
```

However, I keep getting "item length is xxx" in the log msg, where xxx is only hundreds. What I was attempting to achieve is to prevent error page from the target website, so what should I do to fix this problem? Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Well, I come to realize that I do not add an else branch, so when the parse function is called, this method would continue where yield stops. It is such a stupid mistake, sorry!